# To obtain a model view object into a jstl and to transfer it to another jsp page

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a two jsp pages a.jsp and b.jsp, I am fetching my model view object in a.jsp and i want to pass that object into b.jsp 
Here is what i have tried so far.
Obtaining the object into a.jsp works perfectly fine but when i try to access the same from b.jsp it does not work
Somebody please help me
a.jsp:

//To access a model view object

```
<c:set var="type" scope="session" value="${response.type}"/>                        
<c:out value="${type}"/>
```

//The value is coming

//To pass the same object to b.jsp

```
<c:set var="myVar" >
<jsp:include page="b.jsp">
<jsp:param name="myVar2" value="${response.type}"/>
</jsp:include>
</c:set>
```

b.jsp:

```
<c:set value="${param.myVar}" var="itm"></c:set>
<c:out value="${itm}"/></a></p>
```

Does anybody know how to do it?
I tried passing scope as request in a.jsp but still didnt help

Comment: in your controller you can use something like `request.getSession().setAttribute("objectkey", object);`

Comment: have you tried with `${param.myVar2}`

Comment: Yes ${param.myVar2} also didnt give the results

Comment: @Bhargav Modi, Thanks for the suggestion,

Comment: I tried it and its now working, but when two different users login I am having multiple session sharing problem:(

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("objectkey", object);
```

Below is another approach using `FlashAttribute`

```
@RequestMapping(value="<your url>",method = RequestMethod.<POST/GET>)
public ModelAndView loginValidate(HttpServletRequest req, 
RedirectAttributes redir){
...

modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:b");
redir.addFlashAttribute("myVar",yourvalue);
return modelAndView;
}
```